# Salesforce Internal Error in Lightning with Gack Id 850054284

Tags: lightning, error, lightning-apps, gack

I have got stuck with one Lightning Internal Salesforce Error which sporadically happens when I open my lightning app.

I have opened a Salesforce Support ticket but since I can't reproduce issue all the time they refuse to help me despite I have premier support.

The only thing that I got from them is that Gack Id 850054284 is somehow related to 404 Not Found (Application Error).

I have a complex app with many parts and it is very hard to guess which part is raising this error.

I guess that this error coming from force:inputField tag which I use in junction with custom object record property and default parameter.

```
<aura:attribute name="record" type="Custom_Object__c" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Custom_Object__c' }"/>
<force:inputField value="{!v.record.lookup__c}"/>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Did anyone has got the same error?

Can anyone help me or at least suggest why this error sometimes happens and sometimes not and either how to reproduce it constantly or how to make sure it will never happen?

I see that [some similar internal error](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008eSpAAI) happens for force:inputField and picklist and multipicklist, but I am not using picklist neither multipicklist but lookup field.

Comment: Are any of your components using an Apex controller? If so, check your debug logs. A number of times apex errors have shown in lightning as a Gack for me when it was a simple apex error that was visible in the logs.

Comment: I checked. There is no debug logs when I open the app

Comment: Do you see a `reportFailedAction` entry anywhere in the Lightning Inspector action log?

Comment: It is hard to say, I don't use Lightning Inspector since it doesn't seem to work correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Posting answer as this required a support case to resolve*

Finally Salesforce Support accepted this as a bug but they told me

> As per tier-3 update, A known issue cannot be created now

The only details they shared with me was

> Bug Number : W-3415999

They didn't explain to me why this issue is happening only on the first time when the application loads and didn't share deep understanding of reasons to fail in this case.

They promised to fix this bug in next major release which should be  Spring'17